# Trouble with tic tac toe program

Tags: vb.net, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a program for tic tac toe in Visual Basic. I'm specifically having trouble checking for a winner. O works fine, but the program says that X is the winner when there are only two in a row (or if an x is placed in the middle).

Here's my CheckWin sub:

```
  Sub CheckWin()
    If ctr < 9 And board(0, 0) = 2 Or board(0, 1) = 2 Or board(1, 0) = 2 Or board(1, 1) = 2 Or board(1, 2) = 2 Or board(2, 1) = 2 Or board(2, 2) = 2 Then
        If board(0, 0) = 0 And board(1, 1) = 0 And board(2, 2) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("X is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 0) = 1 And board(1, 1) = 1 And board(2, 2) = 1 Then
            MsgBox("O is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 2) = 0 And board(1, 1) = 0 And board(2, 0) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("X is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 2) = 1 And board(1, 1) = 1 And board(2, 0) = 1 Then
            MsgBox("O is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 0) = 0 And board(1, 0) = 0 And board(2, 0) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("X is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 0) = 1 And board(1, 0) = 1 And board(2, 0) = 1 Then
            MsgBox("O is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 0) = 0 And board(0, 1) = 0 And board(0, 2) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("X is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 0) = 1 And board(0, 1) = 1 And board(0, 2) = 1 Then
            MsgBox("O is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 1) = 0 And board(1, 1) = 0 And board(2, 1) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("X is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 1) = 1 And board(1, 1) = 1 And board(2, 1) = 1 Then
            MsgBox("O is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 2) = 0 And board(1, 2) = 0 And board(2, 2) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("X is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(0, 2) = 1 And board(1, 2) = 1 And board(2, 2) = 1 Then
            MsgBox("O is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(1, 0) = 0 And board(1, 1) = 0 And board(1, 2) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("X is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(1, 0) = 1 And board(1, 1) = 1 And board(1, 2) = 1 Then
            MsgBox("O is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(2, 0) = 0 And board(2, 1) = 0 And board(2, 2) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("X is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        ElseIf board(2, 0) = 1 And board(2, 1) = 1 And board(2, 2) = 1 Then
            MsgBox("O is the winner.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        End If
    End If

        If ctr = 9 Then
            MsgBox("The game is a tie.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Call disable()
        End If


End Sub
Sub disable()
    Pic00.Enabled = False
    Pic01.Enabled = False
    Pic02.Enabled = False
    Pic10.Enabled = False
    Pic11.Enabled = False
    Pic12.Enabled = False
    Pic20.Enabled = False
    Pic21.Enabled = False
    Pic22.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is needlessly complicated. I would rewrite entirely rather than debug what you have. Let `board(i,j) = 0` represent an empty square, `board(i,j) = -1` represent an `X` and `board(i,j) = 1` represent and `O`. Then use loops to compute, row, column, and diagonal sums. If any sum is -3, `X` wins, if any sum is 3, `O` wins.